# Need to be able to subclass a mock-patched python class

Tags: python, mocking

I have a sandboxing framework that mocks out a class. Whenever a client tries to make a call to the class, a substitute is provided instead. This works great. However, when a client tries to inherit the patched class, my framework breaks down.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class ProductionObject(object):

    def __init__(self, name):  # The number of args here are being treated as a black box.
        self.name = name

class FakeObject(ProductionObject):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['name'] = 'sandbox_' + kwargs['name']
        super(FakeObject, self).__init__(**kwargs)


@patch('__main__.ProductionObject')
def run(func, mock):
    mock.side_effect = FakeObject
    func()
```

Taking client code and running it through the framework:

```
def foo():
    a = ProductionObject(name='a')
    print(a.name)

run(foo)  # works great

def bar():

    class AnotherProductionObject(ProductionObject):
        def __init__(self, name, val):
            self.val = val
            super(AnotherProductionObject, self).__init__(name=name)

    a = AnotherProductionObject(name='a', val='b')
    print(a.name)

run(bar)  # doesn't work
```

Output

```
sandbox_a                                            <-- this is the correct output
<MagicMock name='ProductionObject.name' id='#####'>  <-- this is broken
```

Comment: A Mock is not helpful for sandboxing. A reference to the original is stored in the Mock object. More generally speaking sandboxing in Python is somewhere between very limiting, not safe and extremely complex to implement. The structure of Python is just too open for it.

Comment: Can I at least get the AnotherProductionObject class to inherit properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following code:

```
@patch('__main__.ProductionObject', new_callable=lambda:FakeObject)
def run(func, mock):
    func()
```

The problem you are having is because `side_effect` only changes what the mock acts as when it is called. When you inherit from the mock you are never actually calling it so you never receive a FakeObject.